# Include de css no ionic

Tags: css, ionic, scss

Preciso chamar um bloco de css, dependendo da condição, em uma view do ionic. Estou tentando fazer com ng-include, mas não funciona.

```
<style type="text/css" ng-include="templates/style.css"></style>
```

ou com div

```
<div ng-include="templates/style.css"></div>
```

Comment: `ng-include` é para `html`, não `css` segundo a documentação: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, resolvi fazendo uma pequena gambi, mas q funcionou pra mim, deixei a resposta aí

Answer (score 0):

Consegui colocando o css dentro de uma div, assim

```
<div><style type="text/css">  //css aqui </style></div>
```

E chamando com ng-include, antes estava passando o endereço errado, com o endereço certo funcionou:

```
<div ng-include="'../../templates/template01.html'"></div>
```